# how to generate a .class file from Class object?

Tags: java, classloader, javassist

I have a class object create from a bytearray:

```
Class localClass = defineClass("me.test.MyClass", pArray, 0, pArray.length);
```

This class is defined fine and i can invoke its methods using

```
localMethod = localClass .getMethod("myMethod", new Class[0]);
localMethod.invoke(null, new Object[0]);
```

Is there anyway to generate a .class file from this Class object?

I tried using java assist but I get a javassist.NotFoundException

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass cc=null;
cc = pool.get(localClass.getName()); //NotFoundException
cc.writeFile("C:\\save");
```

please note that I'm not talking about serialization.

Comment: Why would you need to? The bytes in `pArray` *is* a .class file.

Comment: Thats a good idea, but in fact I dont have access to that array, I use a third party API to get the Class object `Class localClass=ThirdParty.getClass();`

Comment: Thank you that resolved my problem, I found a way to get the `pArray` an just saved it to a .class file using `FileOutputStream`